# How can I show the name of the user with the associated ID from the micropost and user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

This is the database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_02_26_050235) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

The micropost.rb model

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :content, length: {maximum: 140},
        presence: true
end
```

I tried this, but it won't work (micropost.html.erb)

```
<div id="<%= dom_id micropost %>">
  <p>
    <strong>Content:</strong>
    <%= micropost.content %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>User:</strong>
    <%= micropost.user_id %>
    <%= micropost.user.name %>
  </p>


</div>
```

This is what the error shows:
[image]

There is a defined user_id in micropost. I wanted to also show the name of the user with their corresponding user_id

This is the micropost controller code:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_micropost, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /microposts or /microposts.json
  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
  end

  # GET /microposts/1 or /microposts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /microposts/new
  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new
  end

  # GET /microposts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /microposts or /microposts.json
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.save
        format.html { redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost), notice: "Micropost was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1 or /microposts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.update(micropost_params)
        format.html { redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost), notice: "Micropost was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /microposts/1 or /microposts/1.json
  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to microposts_url, notice: "Micropost was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_micropost
      @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: the syntax is correct -- are you sure the micropost has a valid value for the user_id?

Comment: Do all of your `Micropost` records have a non-`nil` `user_id`?

Comment: If you want to have a nullable database column (but do you really?) you need to code defensively and check if there actually is a user. Also Rails on most DBs will default to using `bigint` for primary keys so you'll very likely get a type error if your try to add a foreign key constraint. Do youself a favor and use the `add_reference` method next time instead.

Comment: You don't show your controller code so we can't see where `micropost` in your view is defined. Are you passing an instance variable like `@micropost` from your controller to your view? Please add your controller code and make sure you are showing all of the relevant view code (is `micropost` inside an `.each` loop?)

Comment: @Beartech I have added the micropost controller code

Comment: Ok but you still don't show in your view code how the '@micropost' variable becomes 'micropost'. People are assuming you have a user without a name. But micropost doesn't have a user or you meant to use @micropost in your view instead of micropost

Comment: @Beartech I've checked it and user does not have a name. How can I check if the user does not have a name then it will show a blank and if it does have a name, it will output the name of the user?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the *user* that is associated with *mircopost* maybe don't have a name you have to apply validation in the user model

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

and in your erb file add a safety navigation operator to avoid errors on nil.

```
<%= micropost&.user_id %>
<%= micropost&.user.name %>
```

Comment: If the user existed but didn't have a name then user.name would return "nil" but not a nil error. So the page would work but their name would be shown as "nil". The error the user is getting is telling them that .name is being called on nil. So micropost.user is returning nil. Which means user is not defined.

Comment: yes you are right, I thought name is nil. Thanks for correcting me.
I wonder then how error is not thrown on microsoft.user_id